# Generically Force SeqView to Seq, Scala 2.12

Tags: scala

Is there a generic way to force SeqView to Seq?

In Scala 2.12, SeqView extends Seq, so you can end up with laziness when one might want strict collections.

I was trying to generically force SeqViews to Seqs, but am running into type errors that I'm not familiar with:

```scala
import scala.collection.SeqView
def force(xs: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = xs match {
  case view: SeqView[_,_] => view.force
  case other              => other
}

force(List(1, 2, 3))
force(List(1, 2, 3).view)
```

```
Cannot construct a collection of type That with elements of type _ based on a collection of type _.
```

Scastie link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ThMW8jixT7Odet17EiDavA

Notably, I can provide type parameters to the match, but of course, I get type erasure warnings

```scala
import scala.collection.SeqView
def force(xs: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = xs match {
  case view: SeqView[Int, Seq[Int]] => view.force
  case other              => other
}

force(List(1, 2, 3))
force(List(1, 2, 3).view)
```

The type erasure warning scares me, but it seems to work.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Seq[_,_]` in patten matching you made compiler unable to find right implicit for type class `CanBuildFrom`.

The workaround I came up with, to not have a warning and allow compiler resolve `CanBuildFrom` is just to match against `SeqView[_, _]` and then use `asInstanceOf` to return to original type:

```
import scala.collection.SeqView

def force[A](xs: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = xs match {
    case view: SeqView[_, _]    => view.asInstanceOf[SeqView[A, Seq[A]]].force
    case other: Seq[A]          => other
}

println(force(List(1, 2, 3)))
println(force(List(1, 2, 3).view))
```

I also added the type parameter `A` instead of fixed `Int`.

Another possibility is just to annotate types with `@unchecked`:

```
def force[A](xs: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = xs match {
    case view: SeqView[A@unchecked, Seq[A]@unchecked]   => view.force
    case other: Seq[A]          => other
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Is there potentially any performance issue from which `CanBuildFrom` the compiler selects? I don't know anything about the implementation of `CanBuildFrom`, but my hope was that the various implementations of `SeqView` would each have a specialized implementation of `force`. The fact that `CanBuildFrom` is an argument to `force` worries me that the compiler wants to statically know what `Seq` to turn the `SeqView` into. Do you think this is the case?

Comment: I think it should be no penalty on runtime since it's only resolved on compile time.

Comment: By penalty, I mean that if you have a `SeqView[A, Vector[A]]` but then insist on the `CanBuildFrom` being a `SeqView[A, Seq[A]]` it may convert the `Vector` into a `List`. That would be a large cost when in reality I want it to say a `Vector`.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know exactly how `force` would behave in this case, but I would assume it will keep collection type.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help!